# Solr + Typo3 : Hide facets based on indexConfig

Tags: solr, typo3, facet

Is it possible to hide a facet based on the current table ?

Exemple, I have a "news" table and a table "project".

But if I do this :

```
    facets.state {
        label.data = LLL:EXT:skin/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:search.rfp_state
        field = state_intS
        renderingInstruction = TEXT
        renderingInstruction {
            field = optionValue
            wrap = {LLL:EXT:projects/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_projects_domain_model_requestforprojects.state.items.|}
            insertData = 1
        }
        includeInAvailableFacets = 0
    }
```

The **includeInAvailableFacets** is
for both my **news** and **project**

Looked into the docs, but couldn't find what i've been looking for...

https://docs.typo3.org/p/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/master/en-us/Configuration/Reference/TxSolrSearch.html#faceting-facets-facetname-includeinavailablefacets

Answer (score 0):

Got it !

You have to declare condition to your precise page like this :

Where **1772** is your page id. Found a lead here : https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/8.7/en-us/Conditions/Reference/

```
   [globalVar = TSFE:id =1772] && [globalVar = TSFE:id = {$plugin.tx_anrskin.settings.pages.solrSortDateDesc}] && [globalVar = GP:q =]
        plugin.tx_solr.search.query.sortBy = sortDate_dateS desc
        plugin.tx_solr.search.sorting = 0
        plugin.tx_solr.search.query.returnFields = *, score
        plugin.tx_solr.search.faceting.facets.dateinterval.includeInAvailableFacets = 0
        plugin.tx_solr.search.faceting.facets.item.includeInAvailableFacets = 0
        plugin.tx_solr.search.faceting.facets.name.includeInAvailableFacets = 0
    [globalVar]
```